# Inserting nested properties from another object

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have two arrays`metaObjects` and `justObjects`.

These Objects in both arrays have the `id` property in common.

I would like to create a new array that combines properties from the objects in the different arrays

```
const metaObjects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    metaProp: "metaProp1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    metaProp: "metaProp2"
  }
];

const justObjects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    justProp: "justProp1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    justProp: "justProp2"
  }
];
```

This is the outcome I expect

```
const result= [
    {
      id: 1,
      metaProp: "metaProp1",
      justProp: "justProp1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      metaProp: "metaProp2",
      justProp: "justProp2"
    }
  ];
```

I have tried to implement `map of map` to achieve this

```
const combinedObject = justObjects.map(_w => {
  return metaObjects.map(_m => {
    if (_w.id === _m.id) {
      return { ..._m, ..._w };
    }
  });
}, metaObjects);

console.log(combinedObject);
```

But I get the following error

```
[ [ { id: 1, metaProp: 'metaProp1', justProp: 'justProp1' },
    undefined ],
  [ undefined,
    { id: 2, metaProp: 'metaProp2', justProp: 'justProp2' } ] ]
```

I am not sure why each array has an `undefined` in the inner arrays.
Also I need to flatten the arrays so that they are close to the expected results above.

I have heard about the composable `lens` functions of ramda

Could that be used here?

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly similar to the answer from customcommander, but chooses to use [`groupBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupBy) and [`values`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#values) rather than [`sortBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#sortBy) and [`groupWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupWith). This feels more logical to me, especially avoiding an unnecessary `sort` call.

```js
const {pipe, concat, groupBy, prop, values, map, mergeAll} = R

const joinOnId = pipe
  ( concat
  , groupBy (prop ('id'))
  , values
  , map (mergeAll)
  )

const metaObjects = 
  [ { id: 1, metaProp: "metaProp1" }
  , { id: 2, metaProp: "metaProp2" }
  , { id: 3, metaProp: "metaProp3" }  // unique to `meta`
  ]

const justObjects = 
  [ { id: 1, justProp: "justProp1" }
  , { id: 2, justProp: "justProp2" }
  , { id: 4, justProp: "justProp4" }  // unique to `just`
  ]

console.log 
  ( joinOnId (metaObjects, justObjects)
  )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100vh !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Note that this can easily be adjusted to accept different property name:

```
const joinOn = (propName) =>
  pipe
    ( concat
    , groupBy (prop (propName))
    , values
    , map (mergeAll)
    )
// ...
const joinOnId = joinOn ('id')
```

or to use any common key-generation function:

```
const joinOn = (keyFn) =>
  pipe
    ( concat
    , groupBy (keyFn)
    , values
    , map (mergeAll)
    )
// ...
const joinOnId = joinOn (prop ('id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the object to merge with [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and then use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge them together. This assumes that the object already exists in `metaObjects`, if it doesn't you'll need to decide what to do in that case.

```js
const metaObjects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    metaProp: "metaProp1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    metaProp: "metaProp2"
  }
];

const justObjects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    justProp: "justProp1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    justProp: "justProp2"
  }
];

justObjects.forEach(item => {
   let toMerge = metaObjects.find(obj => obj.id === item.id)
   Object.assign(toMerge, item)
})
console.log(metaObjects)
```

If `metaObjects` is potentially large, it would be better to store it as an object keyed to `id`. Then you could look it up directly without having to search each time.

If you don't want to alter metaObjects, you can `map()` over `justObjects` and create a new array:

```js
const metaObjects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    metaProp: "metaProp1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    metaProp: "metaProp2"
  }
];

const justObjects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    justProp: "justProp1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    justProp: "justProp2"
  }
];

let newArray = justObjects.map(item => {
   let toMerge = metaObjects.find(obj => obj.id === item.id)
   return Object.assign({}, toMerge, item)
})
// metaObjects unaffected 
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could simply combine the two arrays together, group objects by id (you need to sort first) and finally merge each group:

```js
const {
  map,
  mergeAll,
  groupWith,
  eqBy,
  prop,
  concat,
  sortBy,
  pipe
} = R;

const metaObjects = [
  { id: 1,
    metaProp: "metaProp1" },
  { id: 2,
    metaProp: "metaProp2" }];

const justObjects = [
  { id: 1,
    justProp: "justProp1" },
  { id: 2,
    justProp: "justProp2" }];

const process = pipe(
  concat,
  sortBy(prop('id')),
  groupWith(eqBy(prop('id'))),
  map(mergeAll));

console.log(

  process(metaObjects, justObjects)

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) or a `for` loop to convert one of them from an `Array` of objects with an `id` property to an object of objects, using the `id` as the key:

```
const merged = metaObjects.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur.id] = cur;

    return acc;
}, {});
```

Or:

```
const merged = {};

for (const obj of metaObjects) {
    merged[obj.id] = obj;
}
```

Then, iterate the other one while merging each of its entries in the object we have just created above:

```
justObjects.forEach((obj) => {
    merged[obj.id] = Object.assign({}, merged[obj.id], obj);
});
```

Lastly, just convert it back to an `Array` using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```
Object.values(merged);
```

Example:

```js
const metaObjects = [{
  id: 1,
  metaProp: "metaProp1"
},{
  id: 2,
  metaProp: "metaProp2"
}];

const justObjects = [{
  id: 1,
  justProp: "justProp1"
},{
  id: 2,
  justProp: "justProp2"
},{
  id: 3,
  justProp: "justProp3"
}];

// Create an object of one of the two using is id property:

/*
// Alternative using reduce:

const merged = metaObjects.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.id] = cur;
  
  return acc;
}, {});
*/

// Alternative using a for loop:

const merged = {};

for (const obj of metaObjects) {
  merged[obj.id] = obj;
}

// Iterate the other one and merge it with the map you have just created:

justObjects.forEach((obj) => {
  merged[obj.id] = Object.assign({}, merged[obj.id], obj);
});

// Convert it back to an Array of objects:

console.log(Object.values(merged));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100vh !important;
}
```

Note this will work even if any of the two objects contain entries for an `id` that is not present in the other.